# Automatic Powder Detergent dispensing in washing machines - Concept Building

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I have seen the technology for liquid detergent Auto - Dispensing in washing machines where we load the detergent at one go only and the machine automatically dispenses it according to its need for different load cycles.
Now I want a concept and mechanism for the same thing for powdered detergents wherein we load like 1 kg of detergent in the machine and it automatically takes it and uses it acccording to the load.
I need help for this concept can someone advice me with how can I do it

Guys please provide any/smallest of ideas you have as it is only in the concept building phase anything can be of help for me

Comment: Have you considered it might be easier to control liquid cf powder?

Comment: I know that it is easier to control liquid compared to powder but I just want a concept and technique as to how this can be done with the powder.
might be of some help in areas where people use powders more than liquid detergents

Comment: So how do food processing companies control powder? What methods have you researched so far? That way we won't duplicate things and get told you have already considered / discarded that...

Comment: So I saw the mechanism of a coffee vending machine as a possibility - like the coffee powder is dispensed by mixing it with water - the same way we can do it with powdered detergent

Comment: So controlling a liquid instead of a powder - back to my first comment then.

Comment: But the original thing stored is not a liquid, it is in powdered form - I want the powder to get dispensed according to the requirement and maybe go to a smaller compartment below it and then get mixed with water on the way to the drum

Comment: In a coffee vending machine also it dispenses the coffee powder which gets mixed with water on the way and gets to our cups - (the thing stored is eventually a powder)

Comment: The problem is in a moist environment the powder detergent tends to become chunky or even solid, so you can't "pour" it like a dry granulated material. Have to either break it up with a strong mechanism like auger in answer below, or liquify it

Comment: I might look at a "burr grinder" or "burr mill" used for coffee beans -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_mill -- with a feed to force the remaining stock of un-ground material through the mill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Industrial applications use augers to feed powder.

[image]

*Figure 1. An auger system. Image source: [Parker Ionics](https://www.parkerionics.com/powder-coating-equipment/powder-handling-equipment/auger-feed--ace-feed--system_pt30.html).*

In your case you just need the powder hopper and screw.

You could experiment using a horizontally oriented drill bit (say 6 - 8 mm?) in a snug-fitting tube or block. Powder could be feed through a hole in the top side of the tube / block at the end of the drill helix and outlet would be near the tip. Run the drill anti-clockwise for powder feed.

Considerations:

- This arrangement could be driven by a stepper motor to ensure repeatable dosing.
- You may need to consider mounting both ends of the drill bit in bearings to ensure that the drill doesn't gouge out material from the tube / block and add an unexpected ingredient to the washing machine.
- You need to prevent water vapour getting into the feed screw when not dispensing. This is another design challenge as it needs to have free fall-through for dispensing and by quite air-tight otherwise. A butterfly valve might be best. (On the other hand, you might find that dispensing into the machine's powder dispenser is far enough away from the washing drum that humidity isn't a problem in there.)
- You could 3D print an auger.

Other material:

- [Screw Conveyor vs. Screw Feeder](micro auger feed).
- [Fish tank feeder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJi4NlWWm48).

[image]

*Figure 2. An auger made from washers.*

- [Making an auger from washers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JkVqEtmaOg).
- [Screw feed animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvXFsVSCw5Q).