# Seeking Manufacturing Advice: Low-Dose Powder Dosing Device

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, manufacturing-engineering, product-engineering

**Hi** everyone,

I'm working on a project that requires a device to dispense a very small amount of powder (around 1 gram per second) in short bursts. Ideally, the device would "sneeze" the powder from a nozzle once every second.

I'm unsure if a micro-doser or a powder gun would be the best solution for this application. Here's what I know:

**Desired Output:** 1 gram per second dispensed in 1-second bursts

**Desired functionality:** "Sneeze" the powder from 4 nozzles

**My questions are:**

What type of device would be best suited for this application (micro-doser, powder gun, or something else)?

Are there specific features I should look for in this device? (e.g., adjustable flow rate, material compatibility)

Can anyone recommend any resources or manufacturers specializing in such devices?

Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic Powder Detergent dispensing in washing machines - Concept Building](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60018/automatic-powder-detergent-dispensing-in-washing-machines-concept-building)

Answer (score 1):

Determining factors in the choice of device are the density and grain size of your powder.

Paint and powder spray guns exist, but are designed for (quasi)continuous output. Closest to a burst might be cheap electric spray guns where the built-in compressor's pressure-suction cycle is slow enough to be noticeable.

You can create bursts in a device that was not originally intended to via control of the air. For example if you take a powder gun and put a tank with a solenoid at each end between it and its air feed, you can load and release the tank in bursts at the rate determined by the solenoids' capabilities.